# How to run JSONiq from JSON with try.zorba.io

Tags: json, xquery, jsoniq

I need to write a JSONiq  expression that lists only the name of the products that cost at least 3. This is my JSON file which i had typed in the **XQuery** section:

```
{ "supermarket_visit":{
        "date":"08032019",
        "bought":[
            "item",{
                "type":"confectionary",
                "item_name":"Kit_Kat",
                "number": 3,
                "individual_price": 3.5
                },
            "item",{
                "type":"drinks",
                "item_name":"Coca_Cola",
                "number": 2,
                "individual_price": 3
                },
            "item",{
                "type":"fruits",
                "item_name":"apples",
                "number": "some"
                }
            ], 
"next_visit":[
            "item",{
                "type":"stationary",
                "item_name":"A4_paper",
                "number": 1
                },
            "item",{
                "type":"stationary",
                "item_name":"pen",
                "number": 2
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

and this is my JSONiq Xquery JSONiq command, which i dont really know where to type in [try.zorba.io](http://try.zorba.io/):

```
let $x := find("supermarket_visit")
for $x in $supermarket.bought let $i := $x.item
where $i.individual_price <=3
return $i.item_name
```

I am getting many errors in try.zorba.io and im really new to JSONiq and JSON. Is something wrong with my JSON or JSONiq part?

Comment: Note that unfortunately after XQuery 3 the intercorporation of JSON support resulted in two approaches, JSONiq and XPath 3.1/XQuery 3.1, in the W3C standard XQuery 3.1 the selection would be `?supermarket_visit?bought?*[. instance of map(*) and ?individual_price <= 3]?item_name`, see https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMeq.

Comment: Indeed, JSONiq and XQuery 3.1 were optimized to cover complementary use cases (pure JSON querying vs. efficient in-memory map+array structures). The difference is documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919443/what-are-the-differences-between-jsoniq-and-xquery-3-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following selection works for me at the site you linked to:

```
jsoniq version "1.0";
{ "supermarket_visit":{
        "date":"08032019",
        "bought":[
            "item",{
                "type":"confectionary",
                "item_name":"Kit_Kat",
                "number": 3,
                "individual_price": 3.5
                },
            "item",{
                "type":"drinks",
                "item_name":"Coca_Cola",
                "number": 2,
                "individual_price": 3
                },
            "item",{
                "type":"fruits",
                "item_name":"apples",
                "number": "some"
                }
            ],
"next_visit":[
            "item",{
                "type":"stationary",
                "item_name":"A4_paper",
                "number": 1
                },
            "item",{
                "type":"stationary",
                "item_name":"pen",
                "number": 2
                }
            ]
        }
}.supermarket_visit.bought()[$$ instance of object and $$.individual_price le 3].item_name
```

Answer (score 0):

The original query can be slightly modified to (in order to keep a FLWOR expression):

```
jsoniq version "1.0";

let $document := { (: put the document here :) }
for $x in $document.supermarket_visit.bought[]
where $x instance of object and $x.individual_price le 3
return $x.item_name
```

Note that try.zorba.io is an older version of Zorba (2.9) that does not implement the latest, stable JSONiq version. This is why () must be used instead of [] on this specific page. If you download the latest version of Zorba, the above query should work.

Also, the original document provided in the question is not well-formed JSON, because it contains a special em space character (Unicode 2003) on the line above "next_visit". This character must be removed for this JSON to be parsed successfully.