# How to use JSONiq for JSON

Tags: json, xquery, flwor, jsoniq

The question is to write a JSONiq FLWOR expression that can display the name of the products which their price are at least 3.

I have tried the answers provided on [How to run JSONiq from JSON with try.zorba.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55181991/how-to-run-jsoniq-from-json-with-try-zorba-io) but that's not the answers that i expect. Beside that, I also tried a lot of JSON FLWOR expression but still getting errors in try.zobia.io.  This is my JSON file.

```
{
    "supermarket": {
        "visit": [ {
            "_type": "bought", 
            "date": "March 8th, 2019",
            "product": [ {
                    "name": "Kit Kat",
                    "amount": 3,
                    "cost": 3.5
                    },
                {
                    "name": "Coca Cola",
                    "amount": 2,
                    "cost": 3
                    },
                {
                    "name": "Apple",
                    "amount": "Some",
                    "cost": 5.9
                    }
                ]
            },  
            {
            "_type": "planning", 
            "product": [{
                    "name": "Pen",
                    "amount": 2
                    },
                {
                    "name": "Paper",
                    "amount": "One ream"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is my current JSONiq expression.

```
jsoniq version "1.0";
let $a := { (: my JSON file :) }    
for $x in $a.supermarket.visit
let $y = $x.product()
where $y.price >= "3.0"
return $y.name
```

The final output should be `Kit Kat`, `Coca Cola` and `Apple`. I would appreciate some helps for my JSON file or JSONiq.

Comment: Why do you want to write JSONiq? Obviously, the choice of technology is yours, but seeing the non-progress of zorba or JSONiq in the recent years I think it is save to say that JSONiq is dead.

Comment: @dirkk Because It's one of my task which assigned by my lecturer. It need us to rewrite from xquery FLWOR expression to JSONiq.

Comment: JSONiq as a language is alive, maintained and supported. There are other implementations than Zorba out there, for example recently Sparksoniq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visit` also is an array, so you need the parenthesis to get to the individual visits in the `for`. This

```
jsoniq version "1.0";
let $data := { (: my JSON file :) }
for $visit in $data.supermarket.visit()
for $product in $visit.product()
where $product.cost ge 3
return $product.name
```

would return

```
Kit Kat Coca Cola Apple
```

---

Since the above produces a sequence, you can use it anywhere where sequences are allowed.

```
let $data := { (: my JSON file :) }
return string-join(
  for $visit in $data.supermarket.visit()
  for $product in $visit.product()
  where $product.cost ge 3
  return $product.name
, ", ")
```

Result:

```
Kit Kat, Coca Cola, Apple
```

---

Of course this would work as well:

```
for $product in $data.supermarket.visit().product()
where $product.cost ge 3
return $product.name
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer especially with the explanation ! :D